# Search string to find another string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm working on the following simple program:

```
/**
    Recursively searches a string to find a second string.
    @param s the string to search through.
    @param t the string to search for
    @return true if t is found in s.

    Tests whether the string t is contained in a string s.
    For instance, calling the function like this:
        bool b = find("Mississippi", "sip");
    returns true, since "sip" is contained in "Mississippi".
    You must write this as a recursive function, not by just
    calling the string::find() function, or by using a loop.

*/

bool find(const string& s, const string& t)

{
    string temp = s;    
    if(temp.size() < t.size())    
        return false;   
    temp.erase(0, 1);     
    find(temp, t);    
}
```

Here's my testing output:

```
Checking function: Checking the find recursive function. -------------

   + find("Mississipi", "ipi")
   X find("Mississipi", "ipx") should be false, but is true.
   + find("Sommertown", "Som")
   + find("Sommertown", "Sommertowne")
   + find("Somewhere in the middle", "in")

----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Tests passing 4/5 (80%).
```

I've written it about 4 other ways, all similar...including one with find(temp.substr(1),t) instead of the temp.erase.

Would anyone mind pointing me in the right direction? I know it's a simple mistake but I'm not seeing it!

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously, as there is only one return in your function it will only return `false`...

Comment: Your comment is longer than your program. Keep it simple :)

Comment: Not all paths in `find` return a value.  Also, `find` never actually compares `temp` or `s` to `t` (or vice versa), so it will never actually find `t` in `s`.

Comment: It's not only returning false though, 4 of 5 of them are returning true

Comment: @KEYSER: it looks like an actual task description and it's a perfect place for it

Comment: @jlee if 4/5 of the test cases are returning true, something is still wrong - 2/5 of the test cases are supposed to return false.

Comment: There are some things returning the last thing evaluated by your function and that is different from 0, but it does not mean that a `true` value was intended. You should listen to your compiler and set the warning level to "All"...

Comment: And by the way `if(temp.size() < t.size())` will prevent the second test case to ever success.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. That should tell you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your solution:

1. Not all control paths in `find` explicitly return a value
2. `t` is never compared to `s` in any way, so `find` isn't actually checking for `t` - it's simply getting erased, one character at a time.

A better way to write your function might be something like this:

```
bool find(const string& s, const string& t)
{
    string temp = s;

    // Boundary condition which should return true
    if (temp.substr(0, t.size()) == t)
        return true;

    // Boundary condition which should return false
    if (temp.size() < t.size())
        return false;

    return find(temp.substr(1), t); // Recursive call
}
```

^^ Note that in this function, all possible control paths return a value, and `t` will always be compared to `s`.

Also note that I said that in your solution, not all control paths were **explicitly** returning a value.  A C++ function will return a value even if you don't have a return statement, but as @Johan pointed out, it's the last thing evaluated, **not** true.  For instance, I coded up your solution and received the response "224" from `find`, whereas if `find` returned true, I would have received the response "1" - or true.

Comment: This is almost word for word what one of my versions looked like but this is my check test

Comment: TESTING H37, loginID

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Checking function: Checking the find recursive function. -------------------

   + find("Mississipi", "ipi")
   + find("Mississipi", "ipx")
   X find("Sommertown", "Som") should be true, but is false.
   + find("Sommertown", "Sommertowne")
   X find("Somewhere in the middle", "in") should be true, but is false.

----------------------------------------------------------------------

  Tests passing 3/5 (60%).

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I edited my answer slightly.  You don't necessarily have to have `s` and `t` equal to each other - just the first `t.size()` characters of `s`.

Comment: Oh.  I just looked down.  Looks like you figured it out.  Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will always return false. What it does is it removes one character of string s until s.size() < t.size().

I would write the function the following way.:)

```
bool find( const std::string &s, const std::string &t )
{
    return ( s.size() < t.size() ? 
             false : 
             ( s.compare( 0, t.size(), t ) == 0 ? 
               true :
               find( std::string( s, 1 ), t ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly the problem was with OP's code instead of just firing out an implementation. Help OP learn.

Comment: This please! I want to understand my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys:

```
bool find(const string& s, const string& t)
{
    if(s.length() < t.length()) 
        return false;
    else if(s.substr(0, t.size()) == t)
        return true;

    return find(s.substr(1),t);
}

TESTING H37, loginID
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking function: Checking the find recursive function. -------------------
   + find("Mississipi", "ipi")
   + find("Mississipi", "ipx")
   + find("Sommertown", "Som")
   + find("Sommertown", "Sommertowne")
   + find("Somewhere in the middle", "in")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Tests passing 5/5 (100%).

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I appreciate all your help! This site is a godsend for a new programmer!